# I cannot send a String Variable through the pyserial - Python 3 on a Pi

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial

I'm VERY new to Python I'm using a Pi 4, and Python 3 I'm trying to send a variable from a program through the pyserial to use that data on another machine.

The serial port works perfectly because if I use       `ser.write("1-".encode())` it sends it perfectly.

The variable I need is **Temp**  or I can use inTemp retrieved from this line `Obs['inTemp'] = Temp` in my SI7021.py section of a program.

As inTemp is a string I would assume that Temp is also a string
when I try `ser.write((b 'Temp').encode('ASCII'))` it fails with [Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSkm5.jpg)

I then tried  ser.write((b 'Temp').encode('ASCII')) and it failed with a very similar error [Picture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAXox.jpg)

I know the data has to be sent as bytes and in ASCII /UTF-8
Anyone know how I can do it?

Comment: There can't be a space between the `b` and the opening quote mark.

Comment: Thanks
Tried fixing that and got.

 `2020-11-23 17:32:52+0000 [-]     ser.write((b'Temp').encode('ASCII'))
2020-11-23 17:32:52+0000 [-] AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Right, writing the string as a bytestring in the first place removes the need to encode it.

Comment: I cannot do that
it's used in another part of the main program "as is"
Besides I have no idea what a bytestring is or how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You should convert str to bytes as pyserial can read only bytes, try like that:

```
command = str.encode('Temp')
self.session.write(command)
```